# Этимология вопросительного слова «как»

Tags: этимология

Почему наречия, отвечающие на вопросительное слово "*как*", этимологически восходящее к краткой форме прилагательного **мужского** рода кий (какой), представляют собой этимологические краткие формы прилагательных *среднего*, а не мужского рода?

Answer (score 1):

Мало того, что "почему" вообще неприменимо к подобным ситуациям (да потому, что язык так захотел!), так у вас еще наверчено столько странных посылок, что даже разбираться не хочется.

1. Этимологически "как" ни к какой форме прилагательного не восходит. Это фантазии. Во-первых, "как" может быть наречием или союзом, подозреваю, что они этимологически восходят к разным морфам, наречие "как" - результат усечения "како", тоже наречия.
2. На наречный вопрос отвечают наречия, ни к каким формам мужского рода они не восходят. Где вы подобное прочитали?!
3. Вопрос о "среднем роде" вообще пустой. Средний род вообще заменяет всё, что не может быть отнесено к роду. "Что?" - "это". Это своего рода "универсальный" род для всего, что рода не имеет.